# After updating to Ubuntu 22.04, I am no longer able to access Jupyter Notebook

Tags: package-management, python, pip, 22.04, jupyter

When I try to launch Jupyter Notebook, the browser (firefox) launches and I get the following error:

```
Access to the file was denied

The file at /home/benjamin/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-11758-open.html is not readable.

It may have been removed, moved, or file permissions may be preventing access.
```

I tried running

```
jupyter lab clean --all
pip3 install jupyterlab --force-reinstall
```

as per the suggestion from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70753768/jupyter-notebook-access-to-the-file-was-denied. The commands ran, but I still get the Access to the file was denied error. Also, on the reinstall command it spits this out:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
spyder 4.2.5 requires pyqt5<5.13, which is not installed.
spyder 4.2.5 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13, which is not installed.
conda-repo-cli 1.0.4 requires pathlib, which is not installed.
anaconda-project 0.9.1 requires ruamel-yaml, which is not installed.
spyder 4.2.5 requires jedi==0.17.2, but you have jedi 0.18.1 which is incompatible.
spyder 4.2.5 requires parso==0.7.0, but you have parso 0.8.3 which is incompatible.
sphinx 4.0.1 requires Jinja2<3.0,>=2.3, but you have jinja2 3.1.1 which is incompatible.
sphinx 4.0.1 requires MarkupSafe<2.0, but you have markupsafe 2.1.1 which is incompatible.
python-language-server 0.36.2 requires jedi<0.18.0,>=0.17.2, but you have jedi 0.18.1 which is incompatible.
fermipy 1.0.1+5.g5a57 requires astropy<4, but you have astropy 4.2.1 which is incompatible.
```

Then, I tried to force update/reinstall the packages mentioned in the message (spyder and sphinx), and then reinstall jupyter notebook again, but I still get an error message which reads:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.conda-repo-cli 1.0.4 requires pathlib, which is not installed.anaconda-project 0.9.1 requires ruamel-yaml, which is not installed.spyder 5.3.0 requires ipython<8.0.0,>=7.31.1, but you have ipython 8.2.0 which is incompatible.spyder-kernels 2.3.0 requires ipython<8,>=7.31.1; python_version >= "3", but you have ipython 8.2.0 which is incompatible.python-language-server 0.36.2 requires jedi<0.18.0,>=0.17.2, but you have jedi 0.18.1 which is incompatible.pytest 6.2.3 requires pluggy<1.0.0a1,>=0.12, but you have pluggy 1.0.0 which is incompatible.fermipy 1.0.1+5.g5a57 requires astropy<4, but you have astropy 4.2.1 which is incompatible.
```

The last thing I tried was to set

```
c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False
```

and uncomment that line in the file jupyter_notebook_configuration.py, but still the problem persists and I get the error “Access to the file was denied”

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Edit:
Cross posted here: https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/after-updating-to-ubuntu-22-04-i-am-no-longer-able-to-access-jupyter-notebook/13991

here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71983770/just-updated-ubuntu-to-22-04-now-i-cant-open-jupyter-notebook

and on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/uaipzo/i_just_updated_my_machine_to_ubuntu_2204_now_i/

Comment: I tried the pip update, no luck. I tried to download and run jupyter in a virtualenv and a conda env, but in both cases the issues were the same.

Comment: How are you launching the notebook?

Comment: @cocomac just by running the command "jupyter notebook"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I am able to access the notebook now by using the URL printed to the console. (just copy and paste it into the Firefox browser)

I would still like to figure out how to get it to open with just the 'jupyter notebook" command the way it used to work before the update, but for now this is a useful workaround.

Comment: I have a hunch. The problem may be the Firefox. If you use Firefox as your default browser, the new version that came with Ubuntu 22.04 may be the issue. You see, Firefox is now a snap app. If this is true, try to switch the default browser to Chrome or something and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem. Real pain. At least an **interim** solution **is** to use Chrome as the default browser. I really have no idea why the mere fact that it is in a snap store should not stop Firefox working with Jupyter, though.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1243436)

Comment: setting c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False

In the jupyter_notebook_configuration.py file ie c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = FALSE worked for me

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71983770/just-updated-ubuntu-to-22-04-now-i-cant-open-jupyter-notebook